# How to determine the adhesion (sticky) of a block in a cell to a mat-header-cell?

Tags: angular, typescript, css-tables, sticky

I have an Angular table. How do I make the span element in the cells of the first column stick to the sticky mat-header-row when scrolling down the table?

When scrolling the table, the span element should "stick" to the lower border of the mat-header-row and scroll along with the table to the very end of its cell. As soon as the span element has reached the end of its cell, it should "hide" behind the mat-header-row along with its cell.

I have already tried to add CSS styles to the span element, it does not work as I expect

```html
<div class="table-container" style="height: 80vh; overflow: auto">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="height: 200px">
        <span style="position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1">
          {{element.position}}
        </span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use overflow: inherit property for mat-cell
2. Use table tag with mat-table

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I decided to use overflow:inherit for mat-cell.

Comment: its old material problem